# Replacing substring for another string in bash script

Tags: bash, sh, ubuntu-20.04

I'm creating shell script in Ubuntu 20.04 VM, so I'm testing in bash the following:

```
echo ${"/mnt/raid1/"//\//}
```

What I need to achieve is to get the folder's route as valid variable name, something like 'mntraid1'. However previous code throws bash error - bad substitution.

Any orientation appreciated.

Comment: bash, or sh? They're not the same.

Comment: In particular, sh isn't guaranteed to support `${var//find/subst}` at all.

Comment: My actual goal is to create a shell script but since it wasn't working I'm testing it on bash, I'm sorry if they are different questions, I actually don't know.

Comment: If you do want to use this feature, be sure you're writing a bash script instead of a sh script. They're both "shell scripts", but bash guarantees a larger set of features.

Comment: (Moreover, if you're dynamically generating variable names, it's much easier to work with them using other bash extensions -- with baseline POSIX sh you're stuck with `eval`, and there's a lot of [security impact when it's used carelessly](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048); whereas bash gives you [indirect references](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) so you can use "variable variables" safely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a variable name can be in the first position of this [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). Thus, you must assign your string to a variable before running a substitution on it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- this makes your script a bash script

# for extra paranoia, one can add an explicit version check
# otherwise, a user running 'sh yourscript' can override the shebang above
case $BASH_VERSION in '') echo "This script requires bash" >&2; exit 1;; esac

dev=/mnt/raid1
var=${dev//'/'/}
echo "Variable name corresponding to $dev is $var"
```

Note that this is an extension not guaranteed by the POSIX sh standard. It is thus unsafe to use in any script with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang (which only guarantees functionality required by that standard).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think my problem has to do with not being able make my script a bash one, because the code provided by you is working in a VM with another OS.
When I add !/usr/bin/env bash, it throws not found error.